# Web Activity- Post call in ADF with param

Tags: post, oracle-adf

I am able to make a successful POST call in Postman. When I attempt to do the same in ADF, I get a 400 error code.

I don't see anyway to add param to the POST call in ADF, so I added this to the body.
The image doesn't show the entire url..so typing it here
https://bim360field.autodesk.com/api/login_by_auth_token

[image: Post call made in Postman]

Here is a an image of the web activity I created. In the output I can see that the access token is correctly sent in the POST call but I still get a 400 error code saying that the body is malformed.

Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode - '400 : BadRequest', message - 'Endpoint(url) cannot process the request as it could not understand the request (ex: something not right with request body, query parameter or headers)'

[image]

I was able to make the same call in Postman successfully even when instead of param I send the forge_token in the body of the POST call.

[image]